# flutter how to save dynamic list with sharedpreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question, I want to save dynamic list by using sharedpreferences,but only setstringlist method can be used.
For example if I have a list [['a',['b', 'c']], ['d', ['e', 'f']]],how to save it?

Comment: the simplest should be jsonEncode it before you store it as a string.

Comment: Thanks!!! I am new flutter developer, this problem confuse me a lot,and I use jsonEncode it works!Thanks you make my life easy.